# Error 193 - Windows 10, 64-bit, MS Access, ODBC Driver

Tags: oracle11g, windows-10, odbc, 64-bit, ms-access-2016

ODBC-call failed.
Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 193
(MS ODBC for Oracle, c:\windows\sysWOW64\msorcl32.dll) (#160)

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this issue.

Currently, I'm running Access on a remote machine that is on Windows 7 Pro. Company wants this old computer gone, but I can't let it go until my new machine can talk to Oracle via Access.

Comment: As searched everywhere, you don't have a bitness issue? Do you have proper "VC++ 20xx Redistributable package" installed?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'll dig into it. Thank you for the clue.